# Debug locally Python code stored and executed in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, debugging, pycharm

I'm developing some Python scripts in a AWS machine. Usually I use pdb for console debugging from MobaXterm. But it's kind of awful and I'm looking for some more confortable way of doing this.

I know I can config this in PyCharm pro version but I would prefer a cheaper way hehe. Is out there some other IDE/tool with which I could do this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I think you want to access it via a file share or NFS mount.  PyCharm requires local drive access, so you'd have to map it to a drive letter assuming you're using the Windows version.  Edit:  You want to debug it locally while it executes on AWS?  Use an SSH session.  Otherwise, not seeing how you're going to do that.

Comment: Yup, I need to do debugging while it's running in AWS. I saw about SSH through PyCharm plugin but it's pro version only. Do you know any other way?

Comment: I would just ssh into the server and debug it manually.  `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`